# html Как обрезать ссылку

Tags: c#, html

Имеется строка:

```html
"<td width=\"350\" bgcolor=\"#9d8579\"> <br><a href='{0}' target='_blank'><p align=\"center\"><center>{0}</br></a></p></td>"
```

Какие атрибутивы позволяют обрезать ссылку на сайт?

P.S: где

```html
<a href='{0}' target='_blank'>
```

- это генерация ссылок в таблицу {0}
  У меня не получается обрезать ссылку на сайт, как это сделать?
  На скриншоте видно как ссылка выходит за пределы таблицы, мне нужно обрезать её!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот что я хочу чтобы было на ровне всё!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос неоднозначный 1. Обрезать укоротить надпись? - SubString,  2. Сделать авторасширяемый столбец? - уберите width со столбца. 3. Обрезать отображение надписи в столбце - поставить в css стиле td `overflow:hidden`

Comment: Я мало понимаю в html ! дайте пример пожалуйста.. Нужно укоротить ссылку чтобы не выходили за пределы

Comment: Хэлпаните кто нить

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div style="width:50px;overflow:hidden;"><a href='{0}' target='_blank'></div>
```

**width** ширина ссылки, остальное будет скрыто.

Comment: Спасибо огромное получилось )